# Generate co-ordinates that do not overlap

Tags: python

I have a program that is randomly positioning line elements. However, I would like for these lines not to overlap or cross with each other (lines do not touch at all).

Looking up examples on how to do this generally uses a loop to loop through the number of line elements and generate a co-ordinate, then another loop within that loop to check if the co-ordinate is at the minimum distance.

From my experience thus far, using loops really tax the program, and when displaying the stimuli, frames tend to drop.

Another thought I had on doing this is to generate a list of co-ordinates, then calculate the distance of each of those. The codes I have thus far are as below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial.distance
import random

length_line=12
nLines = 1000  #the number of line elements that I want

#Random coordinates for the lines. 500X500 pixels centred around 0
xys = np.random.random([nEls,2])*500-250   

#Calculating the distance of the centre of the lines from each other
dist = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(xys)

minDist = (length_line/2)+2  #the minimum distance that should not cause overlap

print sys
```

I am not quite sure how to progress from here - Ideally I would like the program to keep co-ordinates that have a minimum distance that is more then the set `minDist`, and probably replace co-ordinates that aren't with something else.

Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: The random lines can have any length? Or should they all have the same length?

Comment: @trincot The lines should all be the same length.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to call your objects "segments" instead of "lines"?

Comment: @fralau  - I suppose calling them segments will work too.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to generate **segments** of **line** that do not partially overlap each other? (But they can cross, right?). In the following suggestion, this distinction between segments and lines is essential.

The approach is by simplifying the problem: by **expanding the segments as *lines* (infinite length)**. Checking that two lines do not overlap is trivial (essentially a line is a first degree function, represented with f(0) and a gradient).

*Here I make the reasoning for a two-dimensional space, but it could be extended to a three-dimensional one.*

Two avoid near overlaps, you would have to **round off the f(0) and gradients** in some measure (e.g. one or two digits after the decimal point). That should be faster than calculating distances.

Each time you generate a new segment, you:

1. Expand the segment into a line (compute gradient and f(0)).
2. Check that there is no pre-existing line with that gradient. *This test should eliminate most candidates.*

   - A quick way to do that would to implement a hash table, where the key is the gradient and the value is the f(0), the start and end point).
3. If there is a candidate, check the f(0). *That should also eliminate most remaining candidates.*
4. Finally compare that the two segments do not overlap -- since you already know that both are on the same line, the highest point of the first segment (y dimension) should not not be greater than the lowest of the second segment or vice-versa.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but the lines cannot cross either. In fact, the lines should not touch each other at all.

Comment: Ah. Then the method I suggested will not work because *all lines cross each others except when they are parallel*.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to work it with the type of codes I already have, or is that not possible?

Comment: Hmm... at this point you might want to consult e.g. Don Knuth's works, to see what he devised about it... See: http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html  . See also, e.g.: https://martin-thoma.com/how-to-check-if-two-line-segments-intersect/